# Is it possible to detect what action causes page reload?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Unknown script action (probably async) causes page reload.

How can I find this action in the code?

At least, is there any way to set breakpoint on access to `window.location`?
But I'm not sure that navigation is forced in such way.

In fact I need a way working in any one browser as page reloads in any of them.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497133/178988)

Comment: have you tried Monitor Events..it's Chrome plugin... https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/events?hl=en

Comment: @AAH-Shoot, if you mean `beforeunload` or `unload` - seems like they can't help me as they do not contain stack trace and I can't detect reason of reload there? Or there is a way? Or you have meant some other events?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break javascript before an inline javascript redirect in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360187/break-javascript-before-an-inline-javascript-redirect-in-chrome)

Comment: @Rubén, the question is the same, but 2 of 3 unswers there are not working, the 3rd is hard to use (actually not sure if it works for all cases). I think, answers here are better.

Comment: I know it is years down the track but for anyone else coming this way ..... if you are getting page reloads that you can't track down - it might be a button of type "submit" without a preventDefault on the  attached submit function - it does the POST and the browser redirects after the POST.

Comment: @DukeDougal, it can, but usually it's pretty clear as it is a first thing to check if you are clicking a button.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try opening the **Network** panel, enabling **Preserve log** (which saves the network activity log between page loads) and then recreating the behavior.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25734475/1669860

Comment: In Firefox you can click on a network request and then on the tab "Stack Trace" to see which JS code triggered the navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Better solution for me was to handle unload / beforeunload page events and watch stack trace on debugger breakpoint.

```
['unload', 'beforeunload'].forEach(function (eventName) {
  window.addEventListener(eventName, function () {
    debugger;
  });
});
```

Comment: There is no usefull stacktrace as I remember?

Comment: In my case it showed function with page.reload() call

Comment: Yep, checked it.

Comment: Great, added this to my snippets library https://github.com/tusharshuklaa/chrome-dev-tools-snippets-collection

Answer (score -7):

have you tried firebug?? 
free add-on 
https://getfirebug.com/downloads

It gives many options to debug.
give it a try.

Comment: Every devtools have many possibilities. But I'm searching for a concrete thing. If it is possible using firebug I would like to know how.