# Why when I've more than 1 tab opened of my application, the tabs is constantly reloading (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I've multiple tabs opened on the same application, the application starts a loop of refreshing.
I can't find nothing about it.
It's kinda wird because when I've only one tab opened it works without any problem

I never have this issue, so I'm lost.
Has someone any tip?

Comment: Are you using localStorage or Redux or some other libraries that persist states across sessions?

Comment: Yes, I use both

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing the whole project, but potentially it could be `useEffect` watching a variable that built on localStorage. This could create an infinite loop.

Comment: Start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194971/break-when-window-location-changes/25734475#25734475) and update your question with the details, if it is still actual.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.